# delete a level in a path URL Rewriting

Tags: apache, path, url-rewriting

I have this url:

www.company1.com/level1/level2

I would to rewrite Url to www.company1.com/level2

Is it possible with URL-Rewriting in Apache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This rule should do it:

```
RewriteRule ^[^/]+/(.*) /$1 [L,R=301]
```

If you don’t want to use that rule in the .htaccess file in the document root directory but in the server or virtual host configuration, precede the pattern with a `/`:

```
RewriteRule ^/[^/]+/(.*) /$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: It doesn't function... the url is not rewrited! I used your rule in htaccess: RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^[^/]+/(.*) /$1 [L,R=301]     in level2 dir